# outliers detection and removal in a dataset with categorical and numerical variables

Tags: python, numeric, detection, categorical-data, outliers

I am using the cardiotocography dataset and i have created a dataset of 9 variables and the categorical NSP variable but when i remove the outliers categories 2,3 are deleted in the NSP variable.How can i solve this issue?

My python code is:

```
dataimportances_new=datafeatures_new[['ASTV','ALTV','Mean','AC.1','DP.1','MSTV','UC.1','Mode','Median','NSP']].copy()

Q1_new = dataimportances_new.quantile(0.25)

Q3_new =dataimportances_new.quantile(0.75)
IQR_new = Q3_new - Q1_new
outliers_new=((dataimportances_new < (Q1_new - 1.5 * IQR_new)) | (dataimportances_new > (Q3_new + 1.5 * IQR_new))).sum() 

dataf_new_without_outliers_new = dataimportances_new[(dataimportances_new >= (Q1_new - 1.5*IQR_new)) & (dataimportances_new <= (Q3_new + 1.5*IQR_new))]

print(dataf_new_without_outliers_new.isna().sum())

dataf_new_without_outliers_new.dropna(inplace=True)
```

I was trying to do outlier detection in the dataset with a categorical variable and 8 numerical variables.

Answer (score 0):

Categorical outlier detection is done based on percentage of availability of data for all the categories. I assume you want to detect outliers in Numerical variables and not categorical variable `NSP`. If that is the case, drop the NSP column before calculating the Quantiles you can later join the `NSP` column. Below code should work

```
dataimportances_new=datafeatures_new[['ASTV','ALTV','Mean','AC.1','DP.1','MSTV','UC.1','Mode','Median','NSP']].copy()

nsp = dataimportances_new['NSP']
dataimportances_new = dataimportances_new.drop(columns=['NSP'])

Q1_new = dataimportances_new.quantile(0.25)
Q3_new =dataimportances_new.quantile(0.75)
IQR_new = Q3_new - Q1_new
outliers_new=((dataimportances_new < (Q1_new - 1.5 * IQR_new)) | (dataimportances_new > (Q3_new + 1.5 * IQR_new))).sum() 
dataf_new_without_outliers_new = dataimportances_new[(dataimportances_new >= (Q1_new - 1.5*IQR_new)) & (dataimportances_new <= (Q3_new + 1.5*IQR_new))]

dataf_new_without_outliers_new.dropna(inplace=True)
dataf_new_without_outliers_new = pd.merge(dataf_new_without_outliers_new, nsp, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(dataf_new_without_outliers_new.isna().sum())
```